# How to show that $\int_1^\infty a^{-\lfloor{\log_b x\rfloor}}dx=\frac{a(b-1)}{a-b}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math, riemann-integration

> How to show that $\int_1^\infty a^{-\lfloor{\log_b x\rfloor}}dx=\frac{a(b-1)}{a-b}$?

This was a question in the [MIT integration Bee 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNpa3-EGxGY#) at 59:01. I thought of doing a Riemann sum but I don't know how to calculate the length of the rectangles. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps $$
\int_1^\infty  {}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\int_{b^k }^{b^{k + 1} } {} } \,?
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $b>1$, here is a hint: $$\int_1^\infty a^{-\lfloor\log_b x\rfloor}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{b^n}^{b^{n+1}}a^{-n
}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: How did you find this? Sorry for asking after a long time, but coming to think about it I don't understand how the two expressions are equal.

Comment: @KamalSaleh To start with, since: $$[1,\infty)=\bigsqcup_{n=0}^\infty[b^n,b^{n+1})$$If $b>1$, we can express the integral as: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{b^n}^{b^{n+1}}a^{-\lfloor\log_b x\rfloor}\,\mathrm{d}x$$Assuming it all converges. Consider each interval separately. On $x\in[b^n,b^{n+1})$, $\log_b(x)\in[n,n+1)$ so $\lfloor\log_b(x)\rfloor\equiv n$ for all $x$. So, I get to rewrite the integrand as: $$a^{-\lfloor\log_b(x)\rfloor}=a^{-n}$$

Comment: thanks for clearing this up! But it doesn't seem trivial to me...

Comment: @KamalSaleh Which part doesn't seem trivial, or is confusing?

Comment: I mean the middle expression, you must need deep thinking for this one (or at least I do)

Comment: @KamalSaleh Are you happy with the following idea? $\int_0^2(\cdots)=\int_0^1(\cdots)+\int_1^2(\cdots)$. You probably are. The middle expression is just an extension of that idea. Maybe an easier example is: $$\int_0^\infty(\cdots)=\int_0^1(\cdots)+\int_1^2(\cdots)+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}(\cdots)$$When everything converges. Finally, I just use the partition into the intervals $[b^n,b^{n+1})$ to break up the integral into smaller pieces. Graphically, it's like dividing the 'area under the curve' into a sum of areas under smaller sections of the curve

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you.